# Python: Assign column ids and perform calc depending on column position and id

Tags: python, arrays, list, math

I'm iterating over a file with only a few hundred lines. The data on each line is tab delimited and is essentially (actually around 50 entries per line but you get the idea)

```
ID_value ctrl_val_A ctrl_val_B ctrl_val_C cond1_val_A cond1_val_B cond1_val_C cond2_val_A cond2_val_B cond2_val_C
```

On every line I want to perform a simple calculation for each of the condx_val_y (cond/ctrl). The trick is I only want to calculate using the relevant control (either A, B or C).

I'm not sure of the best (most pythonic) way to do this. I have been pushing the line into a list with line.split('\t') but perhaps list comprehension isn't the best way to go..

I'm sure there is a simple solution, I'm just not using the right search terms or something. Any help would be massively appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the values always in the same order? Like ctrl_val_B will always be the 3rd value in the line?

Comment: If each set is in 3s, then drop the first column and then group by three the remaining string. Next, use `zip` to get your pairs.

Comment: Thanks guys, each line set is the same number as ctrl samples (3 of each in same order A,B,C).. Burhan, would it be possible to provide some basic example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your items are aligned in pairs of three, so you can the modulus operator (`%`) to select the right value for a condition.

```
values = [Avalue, Bvalue, Cvalue]
0 % 3 = 0 # values[0 % 3] => select A
1 % 3 = 1 # select B
2 % 3 = 2 # select C
3 % 3 = 3 # select A again
4 % 3 = 4 # select B again...
# ...
```

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
'''
'''
FNAME = ...
for line in open(FNAME):
    row = line.split('\t')
    values = row[1:4]
    conditions = row[4:]

    for i, cond in enumerate(conditions):
        v = values[i % 3]
        # use cond and v to calculate your value
```